# How to send data from one page to other page in php when the user clicks on the displaying value as said below

Tags: php, html

i am reading names from xml and displaying on php page.how to send this names to another page when user clicks on any name,and how can i save that name in another page till user clicks other value???

Comment: Please show us your code! Also it sounds like you have to learn a little bit more php and html (Maybe a E-Book or a tutorial)

Comment: share code what you have tried.

Comment: for($i=0 ;$i<=$nofile;$i++)
                                {
                                $FileName=readDataFromXml( "/dirInfo/dir".$i."_Info/dirName", $file);
                                $read=$FileName;
                            if ($read!='.' && $read!='..') {
                                                                        echo '<tr><td><a href="data.php?dname='.$read.'">'.$read.'</a></td></tr>';
                                                            }
}

Comment: Please [edit] code into your question, where it can be properly formatted using the code formatting button on the toolbar. Code in comments is unreadable, and no one will notice it there anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    var field1 = $('#field1');
    $('#send').click(function(){
        /* Enter your code */
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'somepage.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'field1value=' + field1.val(),
            success: function(results){
                alert(results);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a task for AJAX. But this means you need to program at least in JavaScript or JQuery for that.

Take a look here at this example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

For 1st, you can pass the name in url by using any variable.
For example: `www.xyx.com?name=your_selected_name`

For 2nd, You can save the clicked value in session variable. when other value is clicked, unset the previous value.

Comment: yeah but how can i do this without redirecting to other page???